# How can I write actual strrchr function in C language?

Tags: c, strrchr

Description
Searches for the last occurrence of the character c (an unsigned char) in the string pointed to by the argument str. The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string. Returns a pointer pointing to the last matching character, or null if no match was found.

[image: Image with examples]

Comment: *Image with examples is posted* No it is not. And please don't post pictures of code or other text.

Comment: Please also read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) Just dumping a task is not the way SO works. Show what you have tried so far. Tell us where **specifically** you are stuck. We can solve specific problems but we cannot replace learning basic stuff.

Comment: I have just started learning C language, and also I do not have any programming background , and posting my first question in Stackoverflow

I have been trying to solve this exercise for 2 days, but it sucks

Comment: Also don't post pictures of text. Post text as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `strrchr()` is very simple to write in C: it suffices to iterate on the string, remembering the last position where the character was seen...

```
#include <string.h>

/* 7.24.5.5 The strrchr function */
char *strrchr(const char *s, int c) {
    const char *p = NULL;

    for (;;) {
        if (*s == (char)c)
            p = s;
        if (*s++ == '\0')
            return (char *)p;
    }
}
```